# Google Cloud Trace NodeJS for bundled applications

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, webpack

I have a server side rendered web application using `express` that we were sending tracing info to Google using `@google-cloud/trace-agent` which worked fine. But THEN.... we bundled our application, and all trace information disappeared. We still see the requests in google cloud console, but now there are no child spans.

I scoured the documentation and stumbled upon this disappointing passage:

> Tracing bundled or webpacked server code.
> unsupported
> The Trace Agent does not support bundled server code, so bundlers like webpack or @zeit/ncc will not work.

From: https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs#tracing-bundled-or-webpacked-server-code

which I thought just meant that I need to start my own root spans... but that doesn't seem to be part of the API.

Does this mean I can't send spans in a bundled server? Is there a programmatic way to manually start root spans in express?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the middleware function from https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs/blob/main/src/plugins/plugin-express.ts and adding it to my express app manually via `app.use(...)`.

For completeness, the code is:

```js
import { get as getTracer } from '@google-cloud/trace-agent';
import type { RootSpanOptions } from '@google-cloud/trace-agent/build/src/plugin-types';
import type { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export function googleCloudTracing(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
  const tracer = getTracer();

  const options: RootSpanOptions = {
    name: request.path,
    traceContext: tracer.propagation.extract(key => request.get(key)),
    url: request.originalUrl,
    method: request.method,
    skipFrames: 1,
  };

  tracer.runInRootSpan(options, rootSpan => {
    // Set response trace context.
    const responseTraceContext = tracer.getResponseTraceContext(
      options.traceContext!,
      tracer.isRealSpan(rootSpan)
    );
    if (responseTraceContext) {
      // This propagates the likes of tracer.constants.TRACE_CONTEXT_HEADER_NAME for cross-service tracing.
      tracer.propagation.inject((k, v) => response.setHeader(k, v), responseTraceContext);
    }

    if (!tracer.isRealSpan(rootSpan)) {
      next();
      return;
    }

    tracer.wrapEmitter(request);
    tracer.wrapEmitter(response);

    const url = `${request.protocol}://${request.headers.host}${request.originalUrl}`;
    rootSpan.addLabel(tracer.labels.HTTP_METHOD_LABEL_KEY, request.method);
    rootSpan.addLabel(tracer.labels.HTTP_URL_LABEL_KEY, url);
    rootSpan.addLabel(tracer.labels.HTTP_SOURCE_IP, request.ip);

    response.on('finish', () => {
      request.route?.path && rootSpan.addLabel('express/request.route.path', request.route.path);
      rootSpan.addLabel(tracer.labels.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_LABEL_KEY, response.statusCode);
      rootSpan.endSpan();
      logger.info('Request tracing ended.');
    });

    next();
  });
}
```